# c++11 default initialization / value initialization / direct initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, initialization, initialization-list

I am mainly confused by the notion of different initialization in c++, particularly in [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) standard.

I am specifically confused by the case where the object is constructed through `new` (relevant or not), and a list of initializers (which matches a user-defined constructor) are supplied, and that constructor does not initialize all members (including PODs and other classes).

The following demonstrates my confusion.

```
class B
{
public:
    int b1;
    int b2;
};

class C
{
public:
    int c1;
    int c2;
    C()
    {
        c2 = 1234;
    }
};

class A
{
public:
    int a1;
    B a2;
    C a3;
    A(int a): a1(a){}
};
```

Now if I write `auto aptr = new A(5)`, can we comment on

1. what will be the value of each fields in `aptr->a1`, `aptr->a2`,
   `aptr->a3`?
2. what initialization is triggered during this process?

---

Supplementary:
A part of the confusion comes from the example included in 
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization

```
struct A
{
    int i;
    A() { } // user-provided default ctor, does not initialize i
};

struct B { A a; }; // implicitly-defined default ctor

std::cout << B().a.i << '\n'; // value-initializes a B temporary
                              // leaves b.a.i uninitialized in C++03
                              // sets b.a.i to zero in C++11
// (note that B{}.a.i leaves b.a.i uninitialized in C++11, but for 
// a different reason: in post-DR1301 C++11, B{} is aggregate-initialization,
// which then value-initializes A, which has a user-provided ctor)
```

Where the value initialization of `B` seems to trigger A's certain initialization (which one is it) that sets A.i. Any comment on this one?

Comment: For me, I would just ALWAYS define constructors that initialize ALL members and then you don't have to worry about what the compiler may or may not do.

Comment: Thanks - I understand. But it would be good to know the actual rules.

Answer (score 1):

> What will be the value of each fields in `aptr->a1`, `aptr->a2`,
>       `aptr->a3`?

- `aptr->a1` will have `5` : because of `A(int a): a1(a){}` and you pass `A(5)`.
- `aptr->a2` will be a default (compiler gnerated) constructed `B` object(i.e. aggregate
  type) having its `b1` and `b2` garbage value.
- `aptr->a3` will be a `C` object constructed by the default constructor provided by you (i.e. `C(){ c2 = 1234;  }`). Meaning `c1` in `a3` will have garbage value, and the `c2` will be initlized with `1234`.

Comment: Thanks, would you explain the code example in the supplement of the question?

Comment: @LiangLuo That itself makes me confusing and that is why I did not consider in my answer. ;) On the other hand, if you are using [tag:C++11] or latter the latter case seems to be something important in the given comments. If you want specific reasoning about the code example, I would suggest asking a different question focussing only on it.